# Can't set password for Mac internet sharing over Wi-Fi

Tags: macos, network, wifi, password, internet-sharing

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I'm trying to host my Mac's internet connection to my other devices. But I can't set the password, nor I can't change my Wi-Fi host name from Wi-Fi Settings panel. I'm trying to change and click "done" but it never sets a password and shows the device a Wi-Fi without a password. I'm on MacOS Sonoma 14.0.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Your question is very well documented. Let me see if I can reproduce this oddity on the 14.1 that’s just released….

Comment: I don't have Sonoma to test, but don't you have to switch it on [at the top] before you can edit it?